# DVI to VGA or a VGA to DVI cables

Tags: dvi, vga

I have a DVI graphics card. And I need to connect with a LCD with VGA port. Which cable I need for this: 
DVI to VGA (female) or a VGA(female) to DVI cables

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/131034/dvi-output-to-vga-monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are adaptors for DVI to VGA. Then you can plug in a standard VGA cable.

i.e. one of these + a standard VGA cable should do it:

[image]

Sometimes they are supplied with your computer.

Notice the four pins around the flat pin; those carry the analog signal required for VGA. A DVI-D port lacks an analog signal and those pins won't fit:

[image]

If your video card only outputs digitally, you could consider an active DVI-D to VGA adapter, which costs around [47 USD](http://www.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/DVI-D-to-VGA-Active-Adapter-Converter-Cable-1920x1200~DVI2VGAE):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit Cees Timmerman.  That analog/digital breakdown is gold.  Explains why the adapter I was using from my macbook couldn't drive the TV.  It was missing the 4 analog pins on the left for some reason.