# windows graphics dvi to analog

Tags: vga, dvi

I'd like to take a HD output which I will have prepared into 4 quadrants, each a virtual screen, and then output these to 4 old vga monitors or even PAL CRT displays.

Do you have any tips on which (off the shelf) hardware we'd need to use. I think we'd probably use a Matrox Quad card, which in theory would give us 16 analog screen outputs, but I don't know how we'd go about spltting each HD output and pushing it to 4 seperate analog screens.

Thanks for considering the question.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DVI to VGA adapters](https://superuser.com/a/248791/103551) but a better option might be the [Radeon HD 5570 1GB VHDCI QUAD VGA](http://www.visiontek.com/vhdci/hd-5570-4-port-vga.html), which supports 7680 x 1080 (2x2 VGA) in Eyefinity mode.

> Single slot, Quad Monitor support is now available for your Small Form
>   Factor Windows Vista, Windows 7 PC. Run up to 4 monitors
>   simultaneously using ATI eyefinity mode. Full support for Microsoft
>   DX11, DX 10.1 and DX9.

For more displays, you could use [multiple cards](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=G2QUAD-PLTVN):

> Use of multiple Matrox G200 MMS PCI video cards allows  connection of up to
>   16 monitors to a single computer.